# How to show HTML with AngularJS from JSON string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonp

I am struggling to display HTML code from JSON string. You can see HTML tags in address. Is there any way I can properly display it?

My template is:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="jsonp_example">
    <ul ng-repeat="item in data">
        <li>{{item.ID}}</li>
        <li>{{item.post_title}}</li>
        <li ng-bind-html-unsafe="getContent(obj)">{{item.custom_fields.sponsor_address}}</li>
        <li>
            <img src="{{item.custom_fields.sponsor_logo}}" width="100">
            <ul>
                <li>
                   <hr>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And script:

```
function jsonp_example($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getContent = function (obj) {
        return obj.custom_fields.sponsor_address
    };

    var url = "https://eventident.com/api/getposts/?auth_key=s2mEus39R296M5F6n343A3dh9c62f7cm&custom_post=sponsors&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

    $http.jsonp(url).success(function (data) {
        $scope.data = data.result;
    });
}
```

Please feel free to amend my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1295z4bc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you include angular-sanitize.js as a dependency ? (as a script and as angular module dependency)

Also, you don't need to `{{}}` with ng-bind-html, just

```
<li ng-bind-html="item.custom_fields.sponsor_address"></li>
```

will do.

Comment: Hi @Komo I have done it: http://jsfiddle.net/1295z4bc/1/   But it still doesn't work unfortuntely

Comment: Did you add it to your module dependencies ? 
```var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);```

Comment: Look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/1295z4bc/4/
You need to use ng-app attribute and set it to your angular module's name.
I also updated angular's version (1.2 is a bit old)

Comment: Super. This is what I needed. Thanks a million @Komo

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the ngSanitize service and directly use `ng-bind-html`.

Here is an updated jsfiddle from yours: http://jsfiddle.net/e01xj547/9/

Answer (score 1):

You might need to explicitly trust the html string by using the `$sce` service. E.g `var trustedHtml=$sce.trustAsHtml('<em>My html string</em>');`

In your case to following usage would be appropirate:

```
function jsonp_example($scope, $http, $sce) {

    $scope.getContent = function (obj) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(obj.custom_fields.sponsor_address);
    };

    var url = "https://eventident.com/api/getposts/?auth_key=s2mEus39R296M5F6n343A3dh9c62f7cm&custom_post=sponsors&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

    $http.jsonp(url).success(function (data) {
        $scope.data = data.result;
    });
}
```

Example usage: http://jsbin.com/zopenoqipi/2/edit?html,js,output